# Fast line-by-line file reader

Tags: c++, performance, file, posix

This is designed for a high performance complex log analyzer. Very simple idea: read a file line-by-line as fast as possible.

I would appreciate any hints what should/could be improved in this code.

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/HappyCerberus/3d6bd6fe1d8dbeeb2929)

**FastLineReader.h**

```
/* Copyright (c) 2015 Simon Toth kontakt@simontoth.cz
 * Lincensed under the MIT license: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

#ifndef FASTLINEREADER_H
#define FASTLINEREADER_H

// STD C++
#include <iosfwd>

/** Quick line-by-line parser of text files for POSIX/Linux
 *
 *  This function provides a fast line parser with a callback model.
 *
 * @param filename file to be parsed
 * @param callback function that will be called for each line
 * @returns 0 on success, -1 if file could not be opened
 **/
int fastLineParser(const char * const filename, void (*callback)(const char * const, const char * const));

#endif // FASTLINEREADER_H
```

**FastLineReader.cpp**

```
#include "FastLineReader.h"

// POSIX
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

// C++ STD
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int fastLineParser(const char * const filename, void (*callback)(const char * const, const char * const))
{
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY); // open file
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        cerr << "Could not open \"" << filename << "\" for reading (" << strerror(errno) << ")." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    struct stat fs;
    if (fstat(fd, &fs) == -1)
    {
        cerr << "Could not stat \"" << filename << "\" for reading (" << strerror(errno) << ")." << endl;
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    posix_fadvise(fd,0,0,1); // announce the desire to sequentialy read this file
    // silent error handling - weak error

    char *buf = static_cast<char*>(mmap(0, static_cast<size_t>(fs.st_size), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
    if (buf == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        cerr << "Could not memory map file \"" << filename << "\" (" << strerror(errno) << ")." << endl;
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    char *buff_end = buf + fs.st_size;
    char *begin = buf, *end = NULL;

    // search for newline in the remainder in the file
    while ((end = static_cast<char*>(memchr(begin,'\n',static_cast<size_t>(buff_end-begin)))) != NULL)
    {
        callback(begin,end);

        if (end != buff_end)
            begin = end+1;
        else
            break;
    }

    // enable if you are working with malformed text files, proper text file needs to end with a newline
#ifdef MALFORMED_TEXFILE
    callback(begin,buff_end);
#endif

    munmap(buf, static_cast<size_t>(fs.st_size));
    // silent error handling - weak error

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `reinterpret_cast` to cast from `void*` to `char*`. `static_cast` is for things like integers and polymorphic types.

Comment: And your tests show that you get a significant improvement?

Comment: @LokiAstari This is based of some relatively up-to-date online tests which I of course cannot find right now :-/

Comment: IT's nice. But why not take it a step further. You can write a streambuffer to wrap your code. That way you can put your code wherever streams are used (and they will be treated like streams) and then people can use your code without changing their existing code.

Comment: @glampert I don't know if I'd present that so straightforwardly. Some (me included) prefer to use `static_cast` when casting from `void*` `static_cast` is just as valid ([arguably more valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/311178/567864) depending on how you read the standard), and it's not vulnerable to future surprises of changing a type somewhere and then attempting an insane cast.

Comment: @Corbin, interesting, I always though the opposite... Just learned something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- `posix_fadvise` conveniently provides a `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL` macro. Use it instead of a magic `1` and a comment.
- The client doesn't know in advance whether the file is malformed or not. Better detect a malformed text file in run time:

  ```
      if (begin != buf_end)
  ```
- A *Bugs* section of `posix_fadvise` man page says that

  > In kernels before 2.6.6, if len was specified as 0, then this was interpreted literally as "zero bytes", rather than as meaning "all bytes through to the end of the file".

  Since you already know the file size, better be safe and call it with `fs.st_size` instead of `0`.
- Move `#include <iosfwd>` to the `cpp` file. The client code doesn't need it.
- `fastLineParser` can be used in C code; just declare it as `extern "C"`
- I see no reason to use C++ here at all. However, if you do so, do not `use namespace std`.
- Finally, do you have any evidence that this is faster than `fgets`?

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with `using namespace std`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be The point of a namespace to isolate names defined by namespace from names defined in your program. By `using namespace std` you create a maintenance problem (collision in the best case, erroneous behaviour in the worst). See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Wait what? How can using namespace create a collision? I'm not defining a new namespace, the function itself still exists inside the global namespace (which it, I admit, probably shouldn't) so that isn't affected and it definitely shouldn't affect the way standard library is linked.

Comment: Oh, OK i finally got what the link is trying to say. Theoretically there could be a name collision between the POSIX headers and STD C++ library headers I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

I see repeated code for the error reporting. Since this is supposed to be a library (I don't see `main()` anywhere), the caller may not want the errors to go to `cerr` anyway. Why not pass in an error-handling callback function?

Also it looks like you're not completely `const`-correct. The `char *` pointers (    `buff_end`, `buf`, `begin`, and `end`) should all be `const` right? And the `static_cast<>` also?